# Incorrect VM Arguments in myEclipse Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse

I have with myEclipse where my web application is failing to start as there is invalid arguments in the Run/Debug configuration i am unable to edit.

Problem started after i installed `JRebel for MyEclipse` and after a short play i uninstalled it and restarted myEclipse.

Ever since uninstallation of JRebel I am receiving following error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ${jrebel_args/server/myeclipse:tomcat6Server}
Exception in thread "main"`

Digging into the Run configuration i can see the following VM Arguments:
`-Dcatalina.home=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Dcatalina.base=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/common/endorsed" -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/temp" -Djava.library.path=C:"/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_19/bin;C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/bin" -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Drebel.log=true ${jrebel_args.server.myeclipse:"tomcat6Server}"`

Now i know i can just delete the offending line and things are ok, but the lines gets applied everytime i create a new runtime configuration via:

`Configure Server connector -> Tomcat -> Tomcat 6.x -> Lunch -> Create Lunch Configuration`

which produces a lunch configuration with following VM Arguments:
`-Dcatalina.home=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Dcatalina.base=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/common/endorsed" -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:"/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/temp" -Djava.library.path=C:"/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_19/bin;C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/bin" -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Drebel.log=true ${jrebel_args.server.myeclipse:"tomcat6Server}"`

In this case I can edit VM Arguments and delete what shouldn't have been inserted. But in case of creating "MyEclipse Server Application" run configuration where the `Arguments` tab is not visible, i am not able to edit the offending line and hence i always get the error.

Not sure what's going on! Even the hot Deploy function is no longer working. Can anyone suggest ways to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the above errors, the following steps need to be taken:

1. Install JRebel
2. Uncheck the jrebel settings - "Enable JRebel agent" and "Enable debug logging" under      *Window > Preferences > MyEclipse > Servers > Tomcat > Tomcat 6.x*.
3. Click on *Apply* and *OK*.
4. Un-install JRebel

Answer (score 0):

Look to tomcat related settings files in under your workspace settings:
WORKSPACEDIR\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings

For my Tomcat 7.x the settings file was:

com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat7.prefs

And there I had a line.
OPT_JVM_ARGS_APP=${jrebel_args.server.myeclipse:tomcat7Server}

I edited the file, removed the line and restarted MyEclipse. This seems to have solved the problem.